# Controller MultipartFormDataContent empty when uploading a file in Blazor Wasm

Tags: blazor-webassembly, asp.net-core-7.0

I am having issues sending a file upload to the controller in a Blazor WASM app.

Here is the controller

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> PostFile([FromForm] MultipartFormDataContent model)
{
    foreach (var file in model)
    {
        var myFile = await file.ReadAsStringAsync();
        string asasas = string.Empty;
    }

    return Ok();
}
```

So the problem is that there are never any files to iterate through. I have also tried the method parameter as `IEnumerable<IFormFile>` but this also has zero elements.

Here is my .razor page

```
<h4>Upload Documents</h4>
<p><b>Supported document files types</b> .pdf,.xls,.xlsx,.doc,.docx,.jpg,.png</p>
<p><b>Max file size</b> 5 MB</p>
<div class="card bg-light">
    <div>
        <label for="formFileLg" class="form-label">Large file input example</label>
        <InputFile class="form-control form-control-lg" multiple id="formFileLg" OnChange="OnInputFileChange" />
    </div>
</div>
```

and the .razor.cs file

```
public partial class UploadDocuments
{
    [Inject]
    public required HttpClient Http { get; set; }
    public string model = string.Empty;
    private List<string> uploadFiles = new List<string>();
    private List<UploadResult> uploadResults = new();
    private int maxAllowedFiles = 3;
    private bool shouldRender;

    private async Task OnInputFileChange(InputFileChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        shouldRender = false;
        long maxFileSize = 1024 * 15;
        var upload = false;

        using var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();

        foreach (var file in e.GetMultipleFiles(maxAllowedFiles))
        {
            if (uploadResults.SingleOrDefault(
                f => f.FileName == file.Name) is null)
            {
                try
                {

                    uploadFiles.Add(file.Name);

                    var fileContent =
                        new StreamContent(file.OpenReadStream(maxFileSize));

                    fileContent.Headers.ContentType =
                        new MediaTypeHeaderValue(file.ContentType);

                    content.Add(
                        content: fileContent,
                        name: "\"files\"",
                        fileName: file.Name);

                    upload = true;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    // Logger.LogInformation(
                    //     "{FileName} not uploaded (Err: 6): {Message}",
                    //     file.Name, ex.Message);

                    uploadResults.Add(
                        new()
                        {
                            FileName = file.Name,
                            ErrorCode = 6,
                            Uploaded = false
                        });
                }
            }
        }

        if (upload)
        {
            var myContent= content as MultipartFormDataContent;
            foreach (var f in myContent)
            {
                var myFile = await f.ReadAsStringAsync();
                string aasa = string.Empty;
            }
            
            var response = await Http.PostAsync("api/UploadDocuments", content);
            
        }

    }

}
```

What is interesting is that the in the following code in the razor.cs file

```
foreach (var f in myContent)
            {
                var myFile = await f.ReadAsStringAsync();
                string aasa = string.Empty;
            }
```

there is an item to iterate through and it is the file I expect. So it works on the client side but when it gets to the controller the file is not there...

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your Controller change the action like this

```cs
    public async Task<IActionResult> PostFile([FromForm] List<IFormFile> files)
```

- use `[FromForm]`
- use `List<IFormFile>`
- use `files` (not model) as parameter's name. be careful on naming.

It should work. In your Razor code, to upload a single file, make the following change in the Razor code

```cs
private async Task OnFileSelected(InputFileChangeEventArgs e)
{
    var files = e.GetMultipleFiles();
    using var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
    foreach (var file in files)
    {
       var fileName = file.Name;
       content.Add(new StreamContent(file.OpenReadStream()), "files",fileName);
    }
    var response = await Http.PostAsync("api/upload", content); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that now works. It was the parameter name that was the issue.